# QStringList remove spaces from strings

Tags: c++, string, qt

What a best way for trimming all strings in string list? I try to use replaceInStrings:

```
QStringList somelist;
// ... //
// add some strings
// ... //
somelist.replaceInStrings(QRegExp("^\s*"),"");
```

but spaces not removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As another answer already told, you need to escape the backslash. You also want to change the expression to match one or more spaces and not 0 or more spaces, try using:
QRegExp("^\\s+")

Answer (score 7):

```
QRegExp("^\s*")
```

\ is special symbol, so you must use `\\` when you need to insert slash into string

```
QRegExp("^\\s*")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you **can use C++11** (qt5 qmake project file: `CONFIG += c++11`), then try this short snippet:

```
QStringList somelist;
// fill list
for(auto& str : somelist)
    str = str.trimmed();
```

It will run through the list with a reference and the `trimmed` function call result will be assigned back to the item in the original list.

**Without the use of C++11** you can use `Qt` methods with Java-Style, mutable iterators:

```
QMutableListIterator<QString> it(somelist);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    it.value() = it.value().trimmed();
}
```

The latter method is just perfect, if you, for instance, want to **remove empty strings** after they have been trimmed:

```
QMutableListIterator<QString> it(somelist);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    it.value() = it.value().trimmed();
    if (it.value().length() == 0)
        it.remove(); 

}
```

The remove is valid, [see the Qt java-style iterator docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#java-style-iterators)

Answer (score 0):

Trimming means to remove spaces in front and at the end of the string. All solutions so far remove only the spaces in front.

Here is the real trimming solution:

```
str_list.replaceInStrings(QRegExp("^\\s+|\\s+$"), "");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
QStringList somelist;

for(int i = 0; i < somelist.size(); ++i) {
    QString item = static_cast<QString>(somelist[i]).trimmed()
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)